# Recuperar información después de filtrar REACT

Tags: reactjs

Lo que quiero hacer es que al buscar por ejemplo escribiendo "as" te sale un listado de videojuegos que empiecen por esas dos letras, hasta ahí todo bien, y si sigo poniendo mas letras pues me siguen saliendo los juegos correspondientes, pero en caso de que por ejemplo, elimino la letra "s" y se quede ponga "a" quiero que me vuelvan a salir todos los videojuegos que comiencen por la letra "a".

La razón por la que no me sale los otros juegos lo entiendo, por que al filtrar se guarda un nuevo array en el state, con esos datos, y ya los otros no existen.

No sé muy bien como hacerlo, aluno consejo para investigarlo

```
 state = {
    games: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://static.nvidiagrid.net/supported-public-game-list/gfnpc.json?JSON"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const games = response.data;
        this.setState({
          games: games,
        });
      });
  }

  filterGameHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
      this.componentDidMount();
    }

    const keyPressed = e.target.value;
    const games = [...this.state.games];

    const filteredList = games.filter((game) => {
      
      const letter = keyPressed.toLowerCase();
      const title = game.title.toLowerCase();
      return title.startsWith(letter);
      
    });

    this.setState({
      games: filteredList,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

lo arregle.

Lo que hice fue simplemente crear un nuevo elemento al estado para guardar las letras.

Y donde renderizo el elemento  lo hice asi

```
 let game = props.games
    .map((p) => p)
    .filter((p) => {
      const keyPressed = props.filter;
      const title = p.title.toLowerCase();
      return title.startsWith(keyPressed);
    })
    .map((game) => {
      return <Game title={game.title} key={game.id}></Game>;
    });
```

Faltaría factorizarlo un poco mejor, pero lo que buscaba lo obtuve.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer el mapeo como dice Fernando o también agregar una propiedad de hidden al objeto game y solo alterar el componente de la lista.

```
 filterGameHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
      this.componentDidMount();
    }

    const keyPressed = e.target.value;
    const games = [...this.state.games];

    const filteredGames = games.map((game) => {
      
      const letter = keyPressed.toLowerCase();
      const title = game.title.toLowerCase();
      return ({...game, hidden:title.startsWith(letter)})
      
    });

    this.setState({
      games: filteredGames,
    });
```